# basic opengl black screen when adding IBO

Tags: c, opengl, glfw, opengl-4

When i only have a VBO and a VAO all works fine but when adding an IBO i'm getting a black screen. Here is the code:

initialisation:

```
GLuint vbo = 0;
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

GLuint  ibo;
glGenBuffers(1, &ibo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

GLuint vao = 0;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float), NULL);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

inside loop:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glUseProgram(shader_programme);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 14, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

vertices and indicies:

```
float   points[] = {
    -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
    1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
    -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
    1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
};

float   indices[] = {
    0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 1, 5, 4, 7, 6, 2, 4, 0, 1
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 5th parameter of [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) is the byte offset between consecutive generic vertex attributes. If it is 0 then the vertex attributes are understood to be tightly packed.

Your vertices consists of three components of type `float`, so the *stride* is `3*sizeof(float)`:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3*sizeof(float), NULL);
```

Since the vertices are tightly packed, you can also pass 0 to the paramter:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
```

---

The type of the indices is `GL_UNSIGNED_INT`. The type of the index array has to be an integral data type which corresponds to `GL_UNSIGNED_INT`. In your case it has to be `unsigned int`.

```
unsigned int indices[] = { .... };
```

Further, the primitive type [`GL_TRIANGLES`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives) consists of a list of indices where each 3 form a triangle. Indices 0, 1, 2 for ma triangle, indices 4, 5, 6 form the next triangle and so on. So the number of indices has to be dividable by 3.

If you want to draw a cube, then the list of indices may look like this:

```
unsigned int indices[] = {
    0,1,2,    0,2,3,
    1,5,6,    1,6,2,
    5,4,7,    5,7,6,
    4,0,3,    4,3,7,
    3,2,6,    3,6,7,
    1,0,4,    1,4,5 
};
```

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
```

Comment: thx for your answer but after doing that i'm also getting a black screen :/

Comment: i tryed with 3*sizeof(float) and 0 but black  screen :/
here is my github if you want to see all the code
https://github.com/Shirakawa42/scop

Comment: @Shirakawa42 `unsigned int` instead of `float` (for the `indices`)